# what is a best way to replace undefined with 0 inside object?

Tags: javascript, object

here is example object:

values inside object not actually called `value1`, `value2`, etc

they all have different names

`data` is data obtained from api.

```
let object = {
  id: '1',
  gen: {
    value1: data.value1, 
    value2: data.value2,
    value3: data.value3,
    value4: data.value4, // etc 
  },
  somethingelse: {
    one: {
      value1: data.value1,
      value2: data.value2,
      value3: data.value3,
      value4: data.value4, // etc 
    },
    two: {
      value1: data.value1,
      value2: data.value2,
      value3: data.value3,
      value4: data.value4, // etc 
    },
    three: {
      value1: data.value1,
      value2: data.value2,
      value3: data.value3,
      value4: data.value4, // etc 
    }
  }
};
```

I know I can add `|| 0` to each but it would be a lot of ugly code
and also sometimes there is math operation which will return `NaN`
and I can't just do:
`if (!object.value1) object.value1 = 0` because I would need like 100 lines of duplicated code for this

Comment: How are you creating this object? You can use recursion and update the `object` after it is created but that seems counter productive

Comment: you can use data.value1 || 0 , if data.value1 is undefined or null (or a falsy value in ecmascript), then it will take 0 or else it will take data.value1 value .

Comment: Could you add the real API results (as an excerpt)? Using `|| 0` is the way to go, for sure that could be done in some kind of loop to save the repetition. However how that could be done depends on the structure of the actual data (wether there are other non-numeric values, wether only some parts need to be formatted, wether that has to be done recursively etc.)

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. I'm sure you aren't using `data.value1` in every nested obejct.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use recursion to replace `undefined` with `0` using recursion.

```js
const data ={}
let object = { id: '1', gen: { value1: data.value1, value2: data.value2, value3: data.value3, value4: data.value4,}, somethingelse: { one: { value1: data.value1, value2: data.value2, value3: data.value3, value4: data.value4, }, two: { value1: data.value1, value2: data.value2, value3: data.value3, value4: data.value4, }, three: { value1: data.value1, value2: data.value2, value3: data.value3, value4: data.value4, } } };
function removeUnf(obj){
  for(let key in obj){
    if(obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === "object"){
      removeUnf(obj[key])
    }
    else obj[key] = obj[key] === undefined ? 0 : obj[key]
  }
}

removeUnf(object);
console.log(object)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the same logic to deeper objects with more loops:

```
for(let key in myObject) {
   if(myObject[key] === undefined || myObject[key] === null)
       myObject[key] = 0;
}
```

If there are more objects in your objects you iterate then the key of keys and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use ES6, you could wrap your data in a [proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) that would return `0` instead of undefined. Then use that to make your object:

```js
let real_data = {value1: 10, value2: 2}

// proxy for real data
let data = new Proxy(real_data, {
  get(target, name, receiver) {
      let val = Reflect.get(target, name, receiver);
      return val === undefined ? 0 : val
    }
});

// just use data now

let object = {id: '1',gen: {value1: data.value1, value2: data.value2,value3: data.value3,value4: data.value4, },somethingelse: {one: {value1: data.value1,value2: data.value2,value3: data.value3,value4: data.value4, },two: {value1: data.value1,value2: data.value2,value3: data.value3,value4: data.value4, },three: {value1: data.value1,value2: data.value2,value3: data.value3,value4: data.value4, }}};

console.log(object)
```

Comment: problem with this is that api not returning `undefined` my object returns it. api is not returning anything if its `undefined`

Comment: @Beke, wouldn't that be like the case in this example where `real_data` has nothing for keys `value3` and `value4`? This will return `0` for any key that's not defined *or* is defined as `undefined`.